# How many ball bearings are used when you take an action to cover an area?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment

It doesn't quite specify in the Adventuring Gear section how many ball bearings you use up, though it does say one bag is 1000 ball bearings.

How many ball bearings are used when you take an action to cover an area with them? Does it use up all 1000 ball bearings?

Comment: this is unrelated, but it always bothered me that they are called "ball bearings" because clearly they are bearing balls and not entire bearings

Comment: Thank you @Nullman for the most epic pedantic comment that is 100% justified. The definition of the word also allows us to understand whether the balls are crushed by someone (i.e. they're physical things, can they take the load of an elephant) or do they trip everyone - they're not *magic* after all? - but I feel when we're analyzing the tensile strength of a bearing ball in RPG we're perhaps taking the game too far ;). Unless we're playing the Dilbert RPG where people play nerds running around a building that then are also playing DnD inside the game (in a sort of pre-inception style rpg.)

Comment: @Jmons If we are going pedantic -  it's compressive strength, and they are ball bearings as opposed to roller bearings. ;-)  Even more pedantically, they are the rolling elements of a ball bearing, since the bearing also includes a race and a cage ... but there ya go, English usage and engineering don't always match up.  (And no, the elephant can't crush it, since the hardness of the elephant's foot isn't sufficient ... )

Comment: And in the typical technology level of Dungeons and Dragons, why do they have ball bearings in the first place? Small metal spheres are fairly difficult to make, and 1000 of them should cost a small fortune.

Comment: @NomadMaker - Small metal spheres are immensely easy to make and available with DND level technology; You need a tall tower, some water and a way of heating metal. [You heat the metal, drop it into a pool below and remelt the ones that aren't round.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_tower)

Comment: @Valorum OK, perhaps I should have said that they are expensive to make. You need a tall tower, a pool of water, and a way of melting metal. This would be much easier to do with magic than it would be with the technology of the time. Now, aside from throwing them on the floor, of what use are they to a medieval culture?

Comment: @NomadMaker - Metal shot would have been highly useful in a variety of ways in medieval culture, notably as an abrasive that could be used to clean metal and semi-precious stones (in a tumbler) and as the deadly element of an explosive-fired canister.

Comment: @Valorum I'll check, but grapeshot was used with the cannon, which is after the medieval times. The same with canister shot. Medieval explosives were very primitive.

Comment: @NomadMaker: The ancient Romans had ball bearings, by some accounts made of bronze, so the technology is doable. They also make good sling bullets, especially if like in a D&D world, slings are used more as individual weapons rather than massed as artillery, as uniform shape makes for more predictable arcs.

Comment: @sharur sling stones? Man I always pictured ball bearings as the size of marbles. Yours must be the size of golf balls. That bag must be huge.

Comment: If characters can buy ball bearings at the village market then it stands to reason they can buy roller skates as well, increasing their Dexterity during melee combat on hard smooth surfaces like in dungeons.

Answer (score 32):

## All of them, by default

The description of [ball bearings](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/ball-bearings-bag-of-1-000) says:

> As an action, you can spill these tiny metal balls from their pouch to cover a level, square area that is 10 feet on a side.

The "these tiny metal balls" refers to all of them in the pouch. At 100 square feet, this is 10 bearings per square foot on average.  Much like drinking half a potion, partial use of an item does not confer the effect.

### Clever uses permitted by DM on case-by-case basis

The rules do not dictate all the uses of bearings, just the one for covering a 10x10 foot area.  Other clever uses of ball bearings may be permitted by the DM without ruining their stated use.

For example, using a bearings or two to determine the slope of a floor (i.e. "magic" sphere of slope detection) probably doesn't remove the ability to use them as a tripping hazard.  Having 999 is likely just as useful.  It's up to the DM to tell you when they're not longer useful for the stated purpose.

Comment: Roll your saving throw against [paradox of the heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox).

Answer (score 10):

### Yes, using an action to cover an area spills all 1000

> As an action, you can spill these tiny metal balls from their pouch to cover a level, square area that is 10 feet on a side. A creature moving across the covered area must succeed on a DC 10 Dexterity saving throw or fall prone. A creature moving through the area at half speed doesn’t need to make the save.

If you are using it for this purpose, then yes, you will pour all of the ball bearings onto the floor.

At DM's discretion, you may be able to do other things like pouring a quarter out to cover a 5x5 foot square but this would be up to the DM.

If I were DM, I would let you do that kind of thing with a Sleight of Hand check to see if you could control how much you pour. After all, it's easy to turn a bag upside down and scatter it everywhere but not as easy to judge how many you are pouring out if you are trying to control it.

Answer (score 4):

### Since it doesn't specify ...

... work it out with your DM.

If you are the DM, pick a number that makes sense to you.

How the game is played:

> 1. DM describes the environment
> 2. Player describes their actions/decisions/choices
> 3. DM narrates the result.

(Paraphrased from p. 4 of the Basic Rules, under the heading 'How To Play')

#### How would I rule it? It uses them all for a 10 x 10 area.

> ... to cover a level, square area that is 10 feet on a side.(Basic Rules, p. 49)

It makes sense to me that each package of 1,000 ball bearings is good for one use, similar to the *holy water,* *alchemists fire*, and the *potion of healing* that are also on the equipment list.  Each unit is good for one use.

For a smaller area, like a 5'x 5' area in a narrow hallway, you might get a few more 'servings' from the bag of ball bearings.

Comment: Save vs OCD or spend the next 10 rounds picking them all up.